# Serializing SQL row of key value pair to JSON object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am building a web form using asp.net c# to generate a JSON string. I have a SQL Server table with columns ID, Columnname, Parent ID, Value.

For a particular ID, if the Id = parentId then it is a parent column, whereas if an id != parentid then it is a child and has a parent. I am pulling these into a datatable from which i need to print a JSON string in a label (as in the actual output)

I tried using Newtonsoft.Json as below

```
foreach (DataRow row in JSONInfoTable.Rows)
{
string result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.serializeObject(row);
testlabel.Text = result;
}
```

But I am getting below result from above code

```
{"Columnname":"Parent1","Value:100"}...
```

Actual Output JSON (Printed in a Webform label after btnclick event)

```
{
    "Parent1" : "100",
    "Parent2" : {
                 "child1" : "300", 
                 "child2" : "40" 
    }
}
```

SQL Server: GetJSON table

```
Id   Columnname  ParentId   Value 
----------------------------------
 1   Parent1         1       100
 2   Parent2         2       NULL
 3   Child1          2       300
 4   Child2          2       40
```

C# Datatable (Pulling data from GetJSON table)

```
SqlCommand Fieldextract = new SqlCommand(Select Columnname, Value from GetJSON, sqlcon);
Dataset ds1 = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter = JSONInfoAdapter ;
JSONInfoAdapter = new SQLDataAdapter(FieldExtract);
JSONInfoAdapter.fill(ds1);
FieldExtract.Dispose();
JSONInfoAdapter = null;
DataTable JSONInfoTable = ds1.Table[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by Columnname  and then serialize it:

```
JsonConvert.serializeObject(JSONInfoTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Columnname));
```